# VBA function - Not able to output variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a vba function to calculate the maximum value of a range of data divided by another. All seems to work well, but problem seems to exist when trying to do Application.Max to an array, where I got around it by doing a loop.
However I cannot recall the Max value outside the loop...
The first Debug.Print prints MaxV value normally, however the second [outside the loop] Debug.Print MaxV resulted in nothing. The CalDS2 function gets an #VALUE! error.

```
Function CalDS2(RangeD As Range, RangeS As Range, MaxMin As String) As Variant    
Dim i As Integer
Dim ArrayDS() As Variant
Dim MaxV As Variant
Dim MinV As Variant
MaxV = 0
MinV = 1000000000
For i = 1 To RangeD.Columns.Count
    ArrayDS(i) = Round(RangeD.Cells(1, i) / RangeS.Cells(1, i), 4)
    If ArrayDS(i) >= MaxV Then
        MaxV = ArrayDS(i)
        Debug.Print MaxV
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print MaxV
CalDS2 = MaxV
End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Andy

*********The new code**************

```
Function CalDS2(RangeD As Range, RangeS As Range, MaxMin As String) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ArrayD, ArrayS, ArrayDS() As Variant
    If UCase(MaxMin) <> "MAXIMUM" And UCase(MaxMin) <> "MINIMUM" Then
        MsgBox "The 3rd argument - MaxMin - must be either Maximun or Mininum"
        CalDS2 = "Error"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim ArrayDS(1 To RangeD.Columns.Count)
    ArrayD = RangeD.Value
    ArrayS = RangeS.Value
    For i = 1 To RangeD.Columns.Count
        ArrayDS(i) = ArrayD(1, i) / ArrayS(1, i)
        Debug.Print ArrayDS(i)
    Next i

    If UCase(MaxMin) = "MAXIMUM" Then
        CalDS2 = WorksheetFunction.Max(ArrayDS)
    Else
        CalDS2 = WorksheetFunction.Min(ArrayDS)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: declare MaxV in the function. `dim MaxV as decimal`. try that first. Other question is why are you using `ArrayDS(i)` ?

Comment: @Hiten004 Right now I am using `Dim MaxV as double`, tried `variant` as well but it is the same. For `ArrayDS(i)`, it was there from the very start where I was trying to do `Application.Max(ArrayDS)`.

Comment: I would `ArrayDS(i)` replace array with variable `Dim yourvariable as double` then try it.

Comment: `Function CalDS2(RangeD As Range, RangeS As Range, MaxMin As String) As ` **Double**

Comment: @hiten004 I have tried but no luck. The first `debug.print MaxV` shows good data, I just wonder why outside the `for loop`, CalDS2 output #VALUE! error (the second `debug.print MaxV` suggested that `MaxV` has no data as it fails to print anything).

Comment: @mehow Tried but same situation.

Comment: this really is strange. what does it look like in the Immediate Window?

Comment: For testing sake, convert this to a `sub` and call it using immediate window or an enclosing `sub`. It will be easy to figure the error there because errors are swallowed in a UDF.

Comment: @mehow I find the root of the problem...The function is for multiple cells, I have enter the range to be larger than they need to be, so there are some empty cells towards the end of the ranges. How do I get around it?

Comment: if you want to skip empty cells then use [isEmpty()](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174338&seqNum=11) function on a range/cell

Comment: Ok got it solved! Thanks everyone for helping!!!

Comment: What happens when `ArrayS(1, i)=0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Enum Op
    Minimum = 1
    Maximum = 2
End Enum

' Call by "=CalDS2(B2:F2,B3:F3,2)"
Public Function CalDS2(r_D As Range, r_S As Range, MinMax As Op) As Double

    Dim x_D() As Variant, x_S() As Variant, x_DS() As Variant

    x_D = r_D.Value2
    x_S = r_S.Value2

    Dim i As Integer, N As Integer, res As Double

    N = r_D.Columns.Count
    ReDim x_DS(1 To N)

    For i = 1 To N
        x_DS(i) = x_D(1, i) / x_S(1, i)
    Next i

    res = x_DS(1)

    For i = 2 To N
        If (MinMax = Maximum And x_DS(i) > res) _
        Or (MinMax = Minimum And x_DS(i) < res) Then
            res = x_DS(i)
        End If
    Next i

    CalDS2 = res
End Function
```

It is much faster then calling the built-in functions, and you read all the values with one sweep into `x_D` and `x_S` arrays.